# How SOAP header should be added in Dynamically invoked web service using c#?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, header, httpwebrequest

The below code invoke the webservice dynamically and process the request.

How to add a soapheader to this dynamically called service?

```html
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl");
WebProxy myProxy = null;
//XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
//string proxyAddress;
System.IO.Stream stream = null;

// Proxy settings if available

HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
stream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12";
importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);
importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
CodeNamespace nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
CodeCompileUnit unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();
unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);

ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);
CodeDomProvider provider1 = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };
CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
CompilerResults results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);

//Invoke the web service
object wsvcClass = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName);
MethodInfo mi = wsvcClass.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyUrl))
((System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol)(wsvcClass)).Proxy = myProxy;
return mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args);
```

Comment: The WebService header method would be like
[SoapHeader("crediantials")]
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetAuth()
        {
          // do something.
         }

Answer (score 0):

Soap headers can be added via the **BeforeSendRequest** method in the **IClientMessageInspector** interface like this:

```
public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        request = buffer.CreateMessage();

        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("SoapHeader", "http://example.com", "crediantials");
        request.Headers.Add(header);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also you can see [this case](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352678/Add-Custom-Message-Header-in-WCF-Calls#:%7E:text=In%20WCF%2C%20to%20pass%20the,SOAP%20Header) for a more detailed example.